# Access product field from variation field

Tags: 8, theming, commerce

There are a bunch of product images that are named same as SKU, so I'm just using *field--commerce-product-variation--sku.html.twig* to show them. All is fine.

I'd like to use the parent product image as fallback image for when the SKU image doesn't exist.

How do I access a parent product field from the product variation field template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll get the variation object in `element['#object']`

```
{% set variation_object = element['#object'] %}
{% set product_object = variation_object.product_id.entity %}
```

then from `product_object` you can access the image field

Comment: That worked! Thanks. Then you can access image URI as `product_object.field_product_img.0.entity.uri.0.value`